# Android : XXHDPI Device Reads XHDPI Values

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-resources

I have an app that will support `xxhdpi` devices but I cannot make it work on emulator (I don't have a real device with me and I want to test it on the emulator.) This is the configuration of the emulator that I am using.

[image: Sony Xperia Z Emulator Configuration]

I tried to get the screen density of the emulator and it gives me `xhdpi` instead of `xxhdpi`. I have values folder for `xxhdpi`named `values-xxhdpi`.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems currently android tools are not properly updated to show correct values.

Comment: If so, then how will I support `xxhdpi` screen density? It uses the `xhdpi` values and it makes the look weird (many elements are so small)? Thanks!

Comment: As android best practices sugges use all the values in DP and SP. If your xhdpi layouts has px values then convert them into DP by dividing px value by 2

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365056/issues-with-avd-manager-v21-0-1-and-21-1rc2-xxhdpi-not-supported) here as well! Restarting adb manually solved the issue for me!