# Android: Unable to run xxhdpi-drawable in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-drawable

I have to extend an application with the new `drawable-xxhdpi` Folder. I'm able to run the simulator, but the application is still loading the graphics from the `drawable-xhdpi`.

I added the folder (eclipse->add new folder) and named it.

[image]

I tried renaming the `drawable-xxhdpi` to `drawable-480dpi` -> no effect

These are my settings for the emulator ([link](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-develop-android-application-for.html)). 
I tried different `Size` like `XLarge` -> no effect):

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more researches, I found a solution  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365056/issues-with-avd-manager-v21-0-1-and-21-1rc2-xxhdpi-not-supported)! Restarting adb manually solved the issue for me!

```
In the Android SDK Tools version 21.1, the xxhdpi screen resolution for 
the emulator display is not yet supported. However, you could do a manual 
override of the LCD properties of the emulator. This will ensure that the 
correct resources are being dispatched for the Xperia™ Z emulator. To do so, 
please execute the following in your command line after the Xperia™ Z emulator 
has completed the boot sequence:

//(on osx/linux use "./adb shell")
adb shell setprop qemu.sf.lcd_density 480

adb shell stop

adb shell start

The emulator will then restart. After it has rebooted the emulator 
should use the correct screen density and UI scaling. We recommend 
you to execute these commends using a batch file or a shell script 
if you are using these settings often.
```

Comment: hi @longlilong, this really helps me get into xxhdpi folder. However as I checked, phones like Sony Xperia Z1's dpi is 441 instead of 480, so should I replace 480 by 441 in order to develop for the Z1?

Comment: @user1509803 No, do not replace. 441 is the device's physical/real dpi. 480 is the xxhdpi density, for devices whose physical dpi is around 480. This makes it easier to support multiple screen sizes and resolutions by grouping them in more general densities (xxhdpi, 480 dpi in the case of Z1). Read http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html.

Comment: tks igordcard, much appreciate :D, I figured it out eventually